# If $A ⊆ B ⊆ C$ and $A$, $C$ are decidable, then $B$ is decidable

Tags: computability, undecidability

I should prove or give a counterexample to the above statement.

In my opinion, this statement is false but I don't manage to find the right counterexample.

My idea was to define $C = Σ^*$ because $Σ^*$ is decidable and contains all the undecidable languages but I fail to find an undecidable language that contains a decidable language.

Comment: A simple hint: have you considered finite languages? And, maybe, the smallest of them?

Comment: @Tonita for B? aren't all finite languages decidable?

Comment: So how about taking a finite language as a decidable?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. There exists undecidable languages.
2. $A = \emptyset$ and $C = \Sigma^*$ are decidable.
3. ????
4. Profit.